# How to pass a value from one DTO to another DTO in html template using thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I am trying to build a personal project in Java, Spring, Thymeleaf etc..

I have a page where a person can buy a product. I am passing a DTO object from the dabase to display data which is already known(Size, Colour, Price, Description etc..) I pass another DTO so that they can customize it according to their own preferences - they can pick a size, quantity, colour etc.. So the problem is that some of the fields do not need to be filled from the customer like ID of the product, or price.

I tried to pass those values from the first DTO to the second one like this:

```html
<input type="number" 
       th:value="${productDetailDTO.getId()}" 
       th:field="*{productId}" 
       th:readonly="${true}" hidden />
```

However the dto arrives with empty field `productId` in the controller. I am not sure if I am using the right approach at all, but I am still learning and I would appreciate some help because I am stuck. Here is my code

```java
@GetMapping("/products-details/{id}")
    public String productsDetail(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
        ProductDetailDTO productDetailDTO = this.productService.getProductById(id);
        List<String> allSizes = productDetailDTO.getSizes();
        List<String> allPictures = productDetailDTO.getThumbnailUrls();
        CartProductDTO cartProductDTO = new CartProductDTO();

        model.addAttribute("productDetailDTO", productDetailDTO);
        model.addAttribute("allPictures", allPictures);
        model.addAttribute("allSizes", allSizes);
        model.addAttribute("cartProductDTO", cartProductDTO);


        return "product-detail";
    }
```

HTML TEMPLATE

```html
<form th:action="@{/cart/product}" th:object="${cartProductDTO}" th:method="post">
<input type="number" th:value="${productDetailDTO.getId()}" th:field="*{productId}" th:readonly="${true}" hidden />
```

Comment: Why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) when asking a question. You can show the relevant formatted code as text, as part of a [mre], instead.

Comment: Side note: A setter should have a `void` return type.

Comment: I am sorry for that... This is my first post ever ^^. I tried to format it. It should look better now. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: How does it look now ? I tried to leave only the most relevant code. I hope now it looks concise and easy-to-understand.

Comment: Set the `productId` on the `CartProductDTO` before returning the view. `cartProductDTO.setProductId(productDetailDTO.getId())`

Answer (score 0):

`th:field` replaces `th:id`, `th:value` and `th:name` in the `input` tag. so if you want to show the value the only way I found is to use the same dto to have the value already to show it or simply to use js to alter the value.